# Proper use of the verb 'eclipse'

Tags: verbs, word-usage, headline-english

I need help settling a debate regarding the correct usage of the verb *eclipse*.

The headline in question is (slightly paraphrased):

> Runner Completes 2mi Run; Eclipses 12m Result

Now, let's assume the 12m result is nobody else's (the runner does not compare himself to any other runner)— but rather a hint at the final result of the runner which is, say, 12:05m.

The headline above uses eclipse in the sense of *achieved a result that is above X*, and not in the sense of *achieved a result which puts the other result in its shadow*. MW dictionary lists *exceed* as one of the translations, but I gather it is in the sense of *exceed an achievement or result made by someone else or at an earlier time*.

Does the headline make a correct/sensible use of the verb given the assumption mentioned above about the result?

Comment: "Eclipse", in the context you describe, is generally used to mean "substantially beat" or "substantially improved on".  The particulars would depend on the sport, but in this case (where new records are likely registered in half-second increments) I'd guess the implication would be that the new time is maybe 10 seconds less than the 12-even prior record.

Comment: The *result* A can be put to shame by the *result* B, even if both results were achieved by the same person. It is the *running time* which was eclipsed, not the runner.

Comment: Ok, and let's say it's the first time this guy is running (it is important for me to emphasize that there is no previous case to reference here)

Comment: Maybe you should use the real headline instead of a paraphrased one because as the reader, I don't know if the "12m Result" is miles or minutes.  And what is the significance of the "12m Result"?  That would also impact how or if "eclipse" is used.

Comment: @vmalloc *Eclipse* is inherently comparative: a body is *interposing* itself between two others, rendering the one *behind* it invisible. The very *presence* of the new body renders the other one (the *prior* one) irrelevant. Consigned to the dustbin of history. In your sentence, if there is not a previous case to reference, then there must have been some reason to believe -- a prior *expectation* -- that 12m is an impressive outcome. In summary: to eclipse requires *three* entities: an audience, a previous champion (or expectation), and a new contender who overshadows that previous champion.

Comment: The material we have to work with needs to be an exact quote. If this were the headline, it would be pointless discussing it as what has been omitted is unclear ('he / she' or 'this performance').

Comment: Ok, so I found this as an example: https://www.simplivity.com/company/news-events/press-releases/simplivity-raises-175m-series-d-funding/. It is not the exact case I was dealing with but it similar enough.

Allow me to explain: in the article, the company crossed the $1B mark in valuation. It is not a previous valuation made, nor is it an achievement made by another company mentioned in the article. It is simply a number that has been reached. Is this a correct use of 'eclipse'? 

I find it weird in this case to say that the valuation (not to say the investment) puts $1B in its shadow...

Comment: @vmalloc That example, plus the explanation you just gave here and the exposition you just provided in your most recent comment under Marius' answer are worth editing into your original question, above. They certainly do help clarify, and once you edit your question it will be bumped back up to the top of the front page, attracting renewed attention and perhaps the kind of answers you're seeking. My personal position will be the same: a benchmark is a benchmark: it demarcates (previously) impressive from not. So it can be eclipsed. But others may share your view and answer from that direction.

Comment: If there was no previous performance to be compared against, there is nothing to be _eclipsed_.  One could say he "beat" 12 minutes, but according to you, he didn't even do that (you said "say, 12:05"); it seems "failed to beat" would be more accurate. The headline makes no sense at all, regardless whether it uses _eclipse_ or some other verb.

Answer (score 1):

I think the sentence is fine.

I feel that both 2a and 2b meanings apply:

> **eclipse** verb
>
> transitive verb
>
> 1 :  to cause the obscuration of :  darken by or as if by an eclipse
>
> 2
>
> a :  **to reduce especially in importance or repute :  cast down (as
>   into obscurity or disgrace)**
>
> b :  **to make insignificant by comparison** :  throw into the shade
>
> Merriam Webster Unabridged Dictionary

See also these samples showing that the usage is well established for quite a while:

> [The Badminton Library of Sports and Pastimes](https://books.google.ca/books?id=shY-AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA107&dq=%22eclipsed%20the%20performance%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=7IM_VbfJM6yCsQSa8oHoBQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22eclipsed%20the%20performance%22&f=false) - Volume 2 - Page 107
>   1887
>
> but in a race at Cambridge soon afterwards Pelham **eclipsed the
>   performance by beating for the first time 2 minutes over Fenner's
>   path**, finishing in the race in front of Templer.

_

> [The Illustrated Official Guide and Tourist's Hand Book to ..](https://books.google.ca/books?id=WRXQg1_faXoC&pg=PA17&dq=%22eclipsed%20the%20performance%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=7IM_VbfJM6yCsQSa8oHoBQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22eclipsed%20the%20performance%22&f=false). - Page
>   17 J. Baxter Langley - 1863
>
> The " Rocket" had thus **eclipsed the performance** of all
>   locomotive engines that had yet been constructed, and outstripped even
>   the sanguine anticipations of its constructors.

_

And if there are any doubts caused by "his own" character of the performance:

> [Reminiscences of an Athlete: Twenty Years on Track and Field](https://books.google.ca/books?id=GbxHAAAAIAAJ&q=%22eclipsed%20his%20own%20performance%22&dq=%22eclipsed%20his%20own%20performance%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=9Yk_VdGqCqHHsQS6qoGACA&ved=0CDoQ6AEwBg) Ellery
>   Harding Clark - 1911
>
> I finished second, with 6189, and Gunn third, with 6111. Sheridan, in
>   the matter of scoring, did not stop here. In 1907 he made a record of
>   7130|, and in 1909 again **eclipsed his own performance with the
>   phenomenal total of 7385**.

Comment: I disagree that these examples are the same. In both cases 'eclipse' references an achievement stated slightly earlier in the page. In the example above it is important that the 12m result is nobody elses. This headline stands alone.

Comment: @vmalloc No prob, but you may want to have a look at the 3rd example.

Comment: @vmalloc But headlines don't stand alone. Headlines are inextricable from the article they head. The point of an article is to summarize and entice people to read the article itself; to that end headlines make reference to facts to be presented (i.e. not explicitly presented in the headline).

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't making myself clear. The assumption is that even in the article that follows, there is no new evidence or new facts about a previous achievement. So to be clear - let's say you have an article with that headline, and even after reading the article you're convince that this is the first time that man runs and he did not break any previously mentioned record or improved on his own previous result. Given this new information - does that headline make sense?

Answer (score 1):

*Does the headline make a correct/sensible use of the verb given the assumption mentioned above about the result?*

Yes, this is a common term for expressing that a previous mark has been passed, or surpassed.

> **Eclipsed, eclipsing, eclipses**:
>
> 1 a: To cause an eclipse of.
>   b: To obscure; darken.
>
> **2** a: To obscure or diminish in importance, fame, or reputation. 
>   **b**: **To surpass**; outshine: an outstanding performance that ***eclipsed the previous record***. The Free Dictionary [eclipse](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/eclipse)

Comment: It seems odd to me that the Free Dictionary chooses to include "outshine"  in its definition 2(b), given that "to surpass" would have handled the job just fine without requiring readers to think of of an overshadowing event as involving superior radiance. _Outshine_ does indeed mean "to surpass," but I doubt that most dictionaries would define it as "to surpass; eclipse." Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary (2003) has this entry for _eclipse_ as a verb: "to cause an eclipse of: as (a) OBSCURE, DARKEN (b) to reduce in importance or repute (c) SURPASS." No outshining necessary.

Comment: @Sven Yargs - yeah, I went to TFD because OP's usage is a colloquial, as is a definition such as "outshine", wouldn't you say? I didn't find "eclipse" in the sense of "pass" or "surpass" in my other sources.